# Why does storing my ActiveRecord Relation in a memoized variable not work the way I expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

EDIT: I'm using Ruby 2.3.3 and Rails 5.2.4.3, FYI.

I have an ActiveRecord model called `Event` more than 7 million records in my database.  When I type the following in my Rails console, the Rails logger tells me that an I/O lookup takes place, which takes about 12.0ms:

```
irb(main):006:0> @events = Event.where("id > 0")
  Event Load (12.0ms)  SELECT  `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE (id > 0) LIMIT 11
```

My expectation would be that, if I were to conditionally reset `@events` to another value using an `||=` operation (such as `@events ||= 'foobar'`), I would *not* see a 2nd `Event Load` statement logged to the screen (because `@events` already exists, so the `||=` would imply there's no need to evaluate the 2nd half of the expression).  However, I *do in fact* see a 2nd lookup take place:

```
irb(main):007:0> @events ||= 'foobar'
  Event Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `events`.* FROM `events` WHERE (id > 0) LIMIT 11
```

Granted, the lookup is much faster (`0.5ms` vs `12.0ms`), but the fact that the I/O is happening at all is what confuses me.  I feel like I'm misunderstanding something basic about how ActiveRecord treats `||=` statements, but I'm not sure what that is.

My goal is to cache the results of the 1st ActiveRecord query in the instance variable, such that subsequent references to that instance variable will not invoke additional I/O calls of any kind, and will therefore save the time that would have otherwise been spent on such an I/O call.

EDIT:
Here's a similar version of the complete sequence of commands I entered into my Rails console (this time with my app's `Role` model instead), along with the abridged results:

```
irb(main):001:0> @roles = Role.where("id > ?", 0)
   (3.9ms)  SET NAMES utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = 'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
  Role Load (22.0ms)  SELECT  `roles`.* FROM `roles` WHERE (id > 0) LIMIT 11
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Role id: 1, name: "Engineering Intern", account_id: 1, created_at: "2013-05-14 23:03:54", updated_at: "2013-05-14 23:03:54", deleted_at: nil>, #<Role id: 2, name: "Operations", account_id: 1, created_at: "2013-05-14 23:04:02", updated_at: "2013-05-14 23:04:02", deleted_at: nil>, 
......


irb(main):002:0> @roles ||= :foobar
  Role Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `roles`.* FROM `roles` WHERE (id > 0) LIMIT 11
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Role id: 1, name: "Engineering Intern", account_id: 1, created_at: "2013-05-14 23:03:54", updated_at: "2013-05-14 23:03:54", deleted_at: nil>, #<Role id: 2, name: "Operations", account_id: 1, created_at: "2013-05-14 23:04:02", updated_at: "2013-05-14 23:04:02", deleted_at: nil>, 
......
```

EDIT:
I hypothesized that maybe under-the-hood there could be a subtle (to me, at least) difference between the way the Ruby interpreter reads `x ||= y` vs. `x = x || y`, so I also tried `@roles = @roles || :foobar`, but I still saw a SQL query logged to the REPL.

Comment: I found a peculiarity regarding `||=` at https://makandracards.com/makandra/21031-careful-with-it-s-not-memoize which which in my situation was true. In a method I was memoizing a DB query result-set but at runtime each time the application invoked that method I saw the query to be executed which puzzled me and the above link helped in understanding the behaviour. My DB query was not returning the results and thus the memoization didn't looked to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the behaviour you're seeing is related to the console. If you do this in the context of a Rails app, it works as expected. For example, I have a `Client` model, and I write a `get_them_all' method like this:

```rb
def self.get_them_all
  @clients = Client.where("id > 52000")
  puts "got them"
  @clients ||= "foobar"
  puts "still have them?"
  @clients
end
```

When I run `Client.get_them_all` in the Rails console, I see a single query to the database. Interesting, too, is that the single query is run *after* the two `puts` statements. Rails only hits the database when it actually has to use the result. Prior to that, it just has what I'll call a nascent query in the @clients variable.

This behaviour means that you can chain the `Client#get_them_all` method with other query snippets, because it's an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. So, in the rails console

```sh
$> Client.get_them_all.class.name #=> ActiveRecord::Relation, not Array
$> Client.get_them_all.where(lastName: 'Escobar') # I can append 'where'
```

Comment: Interesting.  I'm on Ruby 2.3.3 and Rails 5.2.4.3, and I tried adding `self.get_them_all` to my Role model with an identical implementation (except I used `Role.all` instead of `.where("id > 52000")`), followed by `foo = Role.get_them_all` in the Rails console.  Unfortunately, each new invocation of `foo` produced a new query in the console.  The first query is uncached of course, but the subsequent queries are still executed, albeit in a cached fashion.

Comment: @RichieThomas I think what you're seeing is related to the console behaviour. It's a "REPL".  If you run the code in an actual Rails app you will see the caching that you expect.

Comment: @RichieThomas you mention that queries initiated from the console, subsequent to the first one, are cached. I am not seeing that. If you are interpreting the faster query time as meaning cached, I don't think that's the correct interpretation. On a production server you actually see the word "CACHED" in query entry in production.log when it uses a cached query result. I think the caching that accounts for the faster query is a cache of the query plan in mysql (not the query result).

Comment: `It's a "REPL".`  Got it, so somehow a REPL process inherently treats logic like this differently from a server process.  Now you've got me curious about why that is, and what the relevant difference between the process types is.  That said, I added my `.get_them_all` class method to a controller action, and it looks like you're correct about the behavior happening as expected in a non-REPL environment.

Answer (score 0):

**load(&block)** should solve the problem for you.

> Causes the records to be loaded from the database if they have not been loaded already. You can use this if for some reason you need to explicitly load some records before actually using them. The return value is the relation itself, not the records.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-load

```rb
@events = Event.where("id > 0").load
@events ||= 'foobar'
```